# Magento 2 configurable product import issue

Tags: magento2, import, importexport, import-products, product-import

I have uploaded configurable products using csv and it works fine when all the simple products have the same price.

However when the simple products are each having a different price within 1 configurable products they are not displayed.

Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: maybe the visibility issue ?

Comment: I have a CSV file which I import. After import, I am run reindex and check-in frontend. It shows completely with various price. How to send the excel sheet?.